# Who are these "Han Solo" actors?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, actor-identification, han-solo, solo-a-star-wars-story

I recently came across this photo being billed as actors in the upcoming *Solo: A Star Wars Story*. Most of the actors are unrecognizable to me.

Can the actors and, if possible, their characters, be identified?

[image: solosolo]

Comment: I'm reasonably sure the big hairy one was in the original trilogy.

Comment: The top right one plays the character Chewbacca, but I don't recognise the actor.

Comment: I thought my answer to this one was pretty comprehensive, at least with the current info available. Is there anything else you wanted before considering an acceptance?

Comment: @buzz - If you're going to make minor (and pretty worthless) edits, at least get them right.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Per Starwars.com

> **Clockwise from bottom left: co-director Christopher Miller, Woody Harrelson, Phoebe Waller-Bridge, Alden Ehrenreich, Emilia Clarke, Joonas Suotamo as Chewbacca, co-director Phil Lord, and Donald Glover.**
> <sub><sub><sup>*Photo credit: Jonathan Olley ©2017 Lucasfilm Ltd. All Rights Reserved.*</sup></sub></sub>
>
> <sub><sup>[HAN SOLO – SMUGGLER. SCOUNDREL. HERO. A NEW STAR WARS STORY BEGINS](http://www.starwars.com/news/han-solo-smuggler-scoundrel-hero-new-star-wars-story-begins)</sup></sub>

[image]

Alden Ehrenreich plays [Han Solo](http://www.starwars.com/news/emilia-clarke-joins-the-han-solo-stand-alone-film). Joonas Suotamo is Chewbacca. Woody Harrelson is Han's mentor [Beckett](https://nerdist.com/woody-harrelson-star-wars-character-han-solo/). Donald Glover will be [Lando Calrissian](http://www.starwars.com/news/donald-glover-cast-as-young-lando-calrissian-in-upcoming-han-solo-star-wars-stand-alone-film). Emilia Clarke plays the part of [Qi'ra](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Qi%27ra), Han's love interest and Phoebe Waller-Bridge plays a (heavily CGI) droid character named [L3-37](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/L3-37)

Comment: @KodosJohnson - I was hoping the role would go to Jacob Anderson from  GoT. He's got acting talent and range, something Glover is lacking.

Comment: I guess. I was purely thinking of physical appearance.

Comment: @KodosJohnson - Hmm. I still think I'd prefer the better actor, even if he wasn't a strong facial match. Add in the moustache and a wig and you're 90% of the way there anyway.

Comment: Of all the people in the photo, I think Alden Ehrenreich looks the least like Han Solo.

Comment: @MrLister - Including Emilia Clarke?

Comment: Emilia Clarke doesn't even look much like Emilia Clarke here. I did a triple-take when I saw this image in the news the other day and first read the caption.